# Receiving packets via raw socket

Tags: c, linux, ethernet, raw-sockets

I'm trying to receive ethernet packets via raw socket.
But the behavior is not as expected.

The code is here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
 
int32_t main(int32_t argc, int8_t *argv[])
{
   int32_t sock;
   int8_t buf[1522];
   int32_t ret;
   int32_t bytes;
 
   sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
   if (sock == -1)
   {
      printf("socket open failed\n");
      return 1;
   }
 
   ret = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "ens193", (strlen("ens193")+1));
   if (ret == -1)
   {
      printf("interface binding failed\n");
      close(sock);
      return 1;
   }
 
   while(1)
   {
      bytes = recvfrom(sock, buf, 1522, 0, NULL, NULL);
      if (bytes < 0)
      {
         printf("error in recvfrom\n");
         exit;
      }
      printf("bytes = %d\n", bytes);
   }
 
   close(sock);
   return 0;
}
```

And the execution output is here.

```
# ./a.out
[Nothing happening for a while]
bytes = 60
bytes = 42
bytes = 134
bytes = 118
bytes = 118
bytes = 118
bytes = 118
bytes = 118
bytes = 118
bytes = 66
...
...
...
```

But I don't think the interface is actually receiving any packets.
If I see ifconfig output, the RX count is not increasing.
Is it because I am missing something in my code?
If you have some good idea, please let me know!

Comment: It looks like you are capturing all traffic recieved on the specified interface, which might not always count for RX count.

Comment: Do you mean ifconfig does not show the count of all packets receiving through the ethernet driver?

Comment: Since you are capturing `htons(ETH_P_ALL)`, that might be the case

Comment: Why not look what they are with wireshark?

Comment: I think htons(ETH_P_ALL) means receiving all ethernet frame from the device/driver. And the RX count of ifconfig should match to the number of ethernet frames received from the deivce/driver.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at tcpdump/libpcap code and modified my code like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

/* Return the index of the given device name */
static int32_t iface_to_id(int32_t sk, int8_t *device)
{
   struct ifreq   ifr;
   int32_t  ret;

   memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
   strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, device, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));

   ret = ioctl(sk, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);
   if (ret < 0)
   {
      printf("failed to get index\n");
      return -1;
   }

   return ifr.ifr_ifindex;
}

/* Bint the socket to the given device */
static int32_t iface_bind_to_device(int32_t sk, int32_t ifindex, int32_t protocol)
{
   struct sockaddr_ll   sll;
   int32_t ret;

   memset(&sll, 0x0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
   sll.sll_family    = AF_PACKET;
   sll.sll_ifindex   = ifindex;
   sll.sll_protocol  = protocol;

   ret = bind(sk, (struct sockaddr *)&sll, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
   if (ret == -1)
   {
      return -1;
   }

   return 0;
}

int32_t main(int32_t argc, int8_t *argv[])
{
   int32_t sock;
   int8_t buf[1522];
   int32_t ifindex;
   int32_t ret;
   int32_t bytes;
   struct packet_mreq mr;

   sock = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
   if (sock == -1)
   {
      printf("socket open failed\n");
      return 1;
   }

   ifindex = iface_to_id(sock, "ens193");
   if (ifindex < 0)
   {
      close(sock);
      return 1;
   }

   ret = iface_bind_to_device(sock, ifindex, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
   if (ret < 0)
   {
      close(sock);
      printf("interface binding error\n");
      return 1;
   }

   while(1)
   {
      bytes = recvfrom(sock, buf, 1522, 0, NULL, NULL);
      if (bytes < 0)
      {
         printf("error in recvfrom\n");
         exit;
      }
      printf("received bytes = %d\n", bytes);
   }

   close(sock);
   return 0;
}
```

After making change like this, the behavior is as expected.
If I send a ping to the interface ens193.
Then, I see the output like below.

```
# ./a.out
received bytes = 98
received bytes = 98
```

So, htons(ETH_P_ALL) is not the problem.
It seems using "setsockopt and SO_BINDTODEVICE" is not the right way.
Now, my question is then what does SO_BINDTODEVICE mean and when to use it.

If someone has comments on it, please add here.
I'll also look into more.

Comment: SO_BINDTODEVICE sets the interface used by the socket when transmitting, thus bypassing routing.